# Linking Scroll right to scroll down

Tags: javascript, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have created a horizontal scroll site. One issue I am encountering is that the page only works on scroll down and users are consistently trying to scroll right. Was wondering if there is a custom code to "link" the scroll right behaviour to scroll down.?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that whatever mechanism that causes scrolling down to result in horizontal scrolling must lie in your codebase so cannot this be changed?

Comment: Can you show your code so that we can get an idea of your page layout? That would help on devising a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for what Kyle Soeltz was suggesting:

```
    var lastScrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

  window.onscroll = function(e) {
    var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      document.body.scrollLeft = st;
      
      console.log("right");
   } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      document.body.scrollLeft = st;

      console.log("left");
   }
   lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
  }
```

It's tricky to get your page to scroll left and right exactly how you want it so you'll have to experiment with the `document.body.scrollLeft = st;` lines.
You can also use `.scrollBy({ left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });` which is less jittery than the above, but there is a small delay because of the 'smooth' property. e.g.

```
    var lastScrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

  window.onscroll = function(e) {
    var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      document.body.scrollBy({ left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });

      console.log("right");
   } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      document.body.scrollBy({ left: -100, behavior: 'smooth' });

      console.log("left");
   }
   lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
  }
```

Here's how to scroll right to trigger a scroll down event:

```
    var lastScrollX = window.pageXOffset;

  window.onscroll = function(e) {
    var st = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
   if (st > lastScrollX){
      document.body.scrollBy({ top: 100, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });

      console.log("right");
   } else if (st < lastScrollX) {
      document.body.scrollBy({ top: -100, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });

      console.log("left");
   }
   lastScrollX = st <= 0 ? 0 : st; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
  }
```

Comment: Hey! I was able to get the console to log the left and right so it does seem to be working. I think I may have screwed up the explanation - instead of scrolling down to scroll right, i am trying the inverse (where scrolling right = scrolling down).

Comment: You could adjust this code to instead track the `pageXOffset` and adjust the `top` value in scrollBy instead of `left`. However if you cannot currently scroll to the right on your site, you will run into the issue of the scroll event not triggering your function

Comment: @ParkLewisSam I updated my answer at the bottom to include the inverse

Comment: Amazing! Thanks sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

You can look into attaching the [window.scrollBy](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp) method to a function called by the [onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll) event.

Alternatively, if you are using JQuery, there is a mouse wheel plugin that will perform horizontal scrolling. Instructions for setting it up are well defined [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/).

Comment: Can you explain the first option? I tried the jquery plug-in and it isn't working properly